# Слитно или раздельно?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

Ув. филологи! Как правильно написать в этом случае "трудно поддающихся"?
... улучшение результатов лечения различных трудно поддающихся терапии заболеваний.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае  мы имеем дело со словосочетанием, которое может являться термином и писаться слитно. Термины - это  устойчивые словосочетания,  применяемые в науке, технике, искусстве.

КРАТКАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ  ПО ТЕМЕ

А) Термины образуются из словосочетания наречия и прилагательного  или причастия путем сращения: дикорастущий, вечнозеленый, дорогостоящий, высококачественный, легкораненый, узкоспециальный, малоизвестный,  многообещающий.

Б) Существование конкретного термина уточняется  по словарю.

В) Под влиянием зависимых слов термин может перейти в исходное словосочетание с раздельным написанием:  малознакомые места,  глубокоуважаемый человек , но: мало знакомые нам места, глубоко уважаемый всеми человек

Г) В большинстве случаев наречия, входящие в состав термина со слитным написанием, могут входить и в состав словосочетания, где они всегда пишутся только  раздельно и при отсутствии зависимых слов:  маловероятный исход, вечнозеленый кустарник – термины, но: мало изученный предмет, вечно молодой город – словосочетания наречия с прилагательными.

РЕШАЕМ ЗАДАЧУ

А) Существование термина «трудноподдающийся» проверяем по словарю, но в словаре  такого слова нет. Следовательно, мы имеем словосочетание  наречие + прилагательное с раздельным написанием: трудно поддающийся.

Б) Если бы даже такой термин существовал, то при наличии зависимого слова  «терапии» он перешел бы в словосочетание с раздельным написанием.

ВЫВОД

Правильно:  …улучшение результатов лечения различных трудно поддающихся терапии заболеваний.

Comment: Софья, спасибо за очень подробное объяснение!